# kvm: disabled my bios message. delete current install then install via usb drive?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I'm currently getting the kvm: disabled by BIOS message and all I want to do is reinstall. Would it be possible to delete my current OS and use my Live USB to install it once more? I can't access my BIOS to change the virtualization. Would my BIOS be restored to their former glory and let me install or is this just a completely stupid question?

Comment: "I can't access my BIOS to change the virtualization" is the real problem. Reinstalling Ubuntu will never help. Why are you not able to enable virtualization- BIOS password?

Answer (score 1):

Your BIOS is not affected by Ubuntu in any way.

If kvm used to work, but no longer works, you might want to see if you're using another virtualization tool such as VirtualBox. They can't be used at the same time and I think that may lead to a similar error message.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable it in the bios.

install cpu-checker, then do "sudo kvm-ok"
if is says that KVM Acceleration can be used, then you can run a hypervisor, if it doesnt say that, then you either need to enable virtualization in the bios, or buy a new motherboard/cpu.